# Python filter / max combo - checking for empty iterator

Tags: python, filter, iterator, python-3.x, iterable

(Using Python 3.1)

I know this question has been asked many times for the general question of testing if iterator is empty; obviously, there's no neat solution to that (I guess for a reason - an iterator doesn't really know if it's empty until it's asked to return its next value).

I have a specific example, however, and was hoping I can make clean and Pythonic code out of it:

```
#lst is an arbitrary iterable
#f must return the smallest non-zero element, or return None if empty
def f(lst):
  flt = filter(lambda x : x is not None and x != 0, lst)
  if # somehow check that flt is empty
    return None
  return min(flt)
```

Is there any better way to do that?

EDIT: sorry for the stupid notation. The parameter to the function is indeed an arbitrary iterable, rather than a list.

Comment: Yes. ActiveState Python 3.1.2.

Comment: `itertools.c_c_c_c_c_COMBO_BREAKER()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def f(lst):
  flt = filter(lambda x : x is not None and x != 0, lst)
  try:
    return min(flt)
  except ValueError:
    return None
```

`min` throws `ValueError` when the sequence is empty.  This follows the common "Easier to Ask for Forgiveness" paradigm.

EDIT: A reduce-based solution without exceptions

```
from functools import reduce
def f(lst):
  flt = filter(lambda x : x is not None and x != 0, lst)
  m = next(flt, None)
  if m is None:
    return None
  return reduce(min, flt, m)
```

Comment: I'm afraid of `ValueError` being raised by something else than an empty list. Is it known with 100% certainty that min won't raise `ValueError` in any other circumstance?

Also, I may need to replace `lst` with a list comprehension; and in that case, I am even more afraid of `ValueError` caused by my own code inside list comprehension.

Comment: @max, I'm not positive, since Python isn't great about documenting that kind of thing.  However, `flt` should always be iterable.  And even it it weren't, it looks like `min` throws `TypeError` if you pass an argument of the wrong type.  I can't think of anything else `min` itself would throw.  Now, currently it looks like `lst` is a list.  Certainly it's a misleading name if not.  In that case, you don't have to worry about the list comprehension, because it's completely done before `f` started.  If it's a generator comprehension, that's a little more complicated.

Comment: Feels like it's a bit dangerous if Python doesn't document this type of thing. I am, after all, writing the software for the life support module on the spaceship bringing human settlers to... ah never mind :) but I do prefer not to rely on a specific exception type from a builtin unless it's heavily documented.

Comment: If I get it to list, might as well check its length explicitly I suppose.

Comment: @max, I've posted a solution that avoids both the list and exceptions.

Comment: @max - "I'm afraid of ValueError being raised by something else than an empty list." ... does it matter (for higher level purposes) that you make that distinction? I mean, either way, the input was unexpected, right, whether it was `[1,2,3, chicken()]` or just `[]`.

Comment: @detly, yes, but a ValueError thrown by `chicken` might be best handled at a higher level (rather than swallowed by `f`)

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - that's fair enough. Always worth asking, though.

Comment: Note: `min(it)` returns `None` if `it` contains/returns `None`. Thus the non-exception version behaves consistently if your `lst` happens to contain `None`. EDIT: but in this code `flt` never contains `None` anyway...

Comment: "Is it known with 100% certainty that min won't raise ValueError in any other circumstance?" `min` could propagate any exception raised by attempting to compare two elements. This would most commonly be `TypeError`, but a user-defined `__lt__` etc. can raise whatever it likes.

Answer (score 9):

```
t = [1,2,3]
if any(filter(lambda x: x == 10, t)):
   print("found 10")
```

Comment: If you're giving answer other than given answer please explain how its different from others.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(lst):
    # if you want the exact same filtering as the original, you could use
    # lst = [item for item in lst if (item is not None and item != 0)]

    lst = [item for item in lst if item]
    if lst: return min(lst)
    else: return None
```

the list comprehension only allows items that don't evaluate to boolean false (which filters out 0 and None)

an empty list i.e. [] will evaluate to False, so "if lst:" will only trigger if the list has items

Comment: it's simple enough to replace "if item" with a more strict set if you want, however I don't think "", [], set(), tuple() count as nonzero anyway ;) looks like he's going for NUMBERS with his min() call.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the return of filter is empty, you might do (Python3)

`len(list(filter(lambda e : e == 2, [1,2,3])))`

But notice, hence filter is a generator if you this test twice, second time, you will receive a diferent result:

`len(list(filter(lambda e : e == 2, [1,2,3])))
len(list(filter(lambda e : e == 2, [1,2,3])))`

>>> 1

>>> 1

But:

`f = filter(lambda e : e == 2, [1,2,3])
len(list(f))
len(list(f))`

>>> 1

>>> 0

Comment: Converting to a list just to see if the iterator is empty is both inefficient and verbose.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for reduce expression too `return reduce(lambda a,b: a<b and a or b,x) or None`

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, this still has issues with empty iterators or empty lists.