# python list(zipobject) returns empty (list) container

Tags: python, list

I have run into a strange issue in Python 3.4.3, and it doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere.

Lets say: 
`a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b = [5,6,7,8]`

To concatenate these vertically: `ab = zip(a,b)` 
in python 3, `ab` itself would return:

> zip object at (some hexnumber)

All well here, in python 3, to retrieve the concatenated list: 
`aabb = list(ab)`

Now heres the issue, first time, `aabb` will indeed return a real list: 
`[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]`

Second time and onwards however, if you do the whole process again `list(aabb)` will simply return an empty `[]` container, just like `list()` would do.

It will only work again after I restart shell/interpreter.

Is this normal or a bug?

**EDIT**: Ok guys I didn't realise it was to do with `zip`, it SEEMED constant as `ab` returned the same hex value everytime so I thought it was to do with `list(ab)`.

Anyway, worked out by reassigning `ab = zip(ab)`

From what I understand in answers and  original link, `ab` gets disposed once read.

Comment: @vaultah i don't see anywhere in that section of the docs that `list(list(zip([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]))) == []`.  perhaps you can explain?  @DonD, this is what you're saying you're getting?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940072/exhausted-iterators-what-to-do-about-them

Comment: @vaultah please elaborate, it doesn't say it why it works once only. and why was it downvoted soon as I posted it.

Comment: @vaultah The biggest problem is that `list(aabb)` doesn't return an empty list as the argument is a filled list not an empty iterator. The question states an incorrect problem without a full code sample.

Comment: @dbliss That is a false statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem will not be created by `list(aabb)` but with `list(ab)` in your code right now:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

ab = zip(a, b)
aabb = list(ab)

print(list(ab))  # -> []
```

The problem is that `zip` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) which stores values once and are then disposed like so:

```
ab = zip(a, b)  # iterator created
aabb = list(ab)  # elements read from ab, disposed, placed in a list

print(list(ab))  # now ab has nothing because it was exhausted
```

This on the other hand should work because `aabb` is just a list, not the exhausted iterator `ab`:

```
ab = zip(a, b)
aabb = list(ab)

print(list(aabb))  # -> [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```