# Why does zip return no items after initial use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, type-conversion

in below code i want test `zip()` method. in one example i iterate in b (zip output) and the second convert b to the set.but  when i convert the b to set strange thing happened. the ones that iterate in b, print it output is empty list. but when i comment the `c = set(b)` and `print(c)` the output is correct what happen and why? can you explain for me.

```
    l1 = range(10)
    l2 = range(10)
    b = zip(l1,l2)
    c = set(b)
    print(c)
    result = [(x,y) for x,y in b]
    print(len(result))
```

Comment: `zip` returns an iterator. Calling `set` on that iterator consumes it, making it empty. When the list comprehension `[(x,y) for x,y in b]` is executed, `b` is empty and you get an empty list.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you give me a reference for more study please

Comment: You mean about iterators? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)

Comment: i mean for exhausted iterator

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything specifically about exhausted iterators. Asking for a reference about exhausted iterators is like asking for a reference about the number 4. Why should there be a reference about the number 4? 4 is a number like any other. It's not really special. You should just learn about numbers in general instead.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is an iterator which you have exhausted.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip), `zip` is equivalent to the generator function below (notice the `yield` statement):

```
def zip(*iterables):
    # zip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    sentinel = object()
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    while iterators:
        result = []
        for it in iterators:
            elem = next(it, sentinel)
            if elem is sentinel:
                return
            result.append(elem)
        yield tuple(result)
```

You can exhaust a generator in many ways. For example, by calling `list` or `set` on it, or by applying `next` until it exhausts.

Since you have called `set` on the generator, its contents are emptied and are no longer iterable, unless they have been stored via the exhausting function.

You can find some examples and solutions in [exhausted iterators - what to do about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940072/exhausted-iterators-what-to-do-about-them). In particular, `itertools.tee` can conveniently copy an iterator so that you can "reuse" it.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you offer me reference for learning more about exhausted iterator

Comment: @arashmoradi, see update.