# In Python, how does one catch warnings as if they were exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, warnings

A third-party library (written in C) that I use in my python code is issuing warnings. I want to be able to use the `try` `except` syntax to properly handle these warnings. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are those warning just text messages written do stderr?

Comment: Fenikso: I don't know for sure, seems like real warnings

Comment: How do you recognize "real warning"? I thought that in C you get real warning during compile.

Comment: `warnings.filterwarnings` does exactly what you want, I don't understand what your issue with it is?

Comment: @Fenikso, @Rosh Oxymoron you were right. My mistake. `warnings.filterwarnigns('error')` does the job. I can't find the original answer that proposed this solution

Answer (score 279, accepted):

To handle warnings as errors simply use this:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")
```

After this you will be able to catch warnings same as errors, e.g. this will work:

```
try:
    some_heavy_calculations()
except RuntimeWarning:
    breakpoint()
```

You can also reset the behaviour of warnings by running:

```
warnings.resetwarnings()
```

P.S. Added this answer because the best answer in comments contains misspelling: `filterwarnigns` instead of `filterwarnings`.

Comment: And if you just want to see a stack trace, the first two lines are all you need.

Comment: This is perfect. I just wanted my script to stop execution as soon as the warning was issued, so that I could print relevant debug information and fix the issue.

Comment: You don't need the `filterwarnings` call in order to catch `Warnings`, at least in python 3. it just works.

Comment: The accepted answer does not answer the OP's question. This answer does. This is the answer I was looking for when my search found this question.

Comment: Converting all warnings to errors can easily become problematic if you're using this within a larger script or software package. Can make things very hard to debug as well

Comment: Use warnings.resetwarnings() to reset when you're done

Comment: I am still seeing warnings after `warnings.resetwarnings()` in Jupyter notebook. It does not interrupt the program but they were not showing up earlier. It's all `DeprecationWarning`. Any clue?

Comment: The exception msg is different from the original warning msg. I get something with `<built-in method XXX of YYY object at 0x7f614ebe3880> returned a result with an exception set` instead of `/home/user/.../test.py:103: RuntimeWarning: This-Is-A-Warning-Message`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 78):

To quote from the python handbook ([27.6.4. Testing Warnings](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings)):

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    # Trigger a warning.
    fxn()
    # Verify some things
    assert len(w) == 1
    assert issubclass(w[-1].category, DeprecationWarning)
    assert "deprecated" in str(w[-1].message)
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934081/461597) is an answer, that tells you how to use the `try` `except` syntax.

Comment: This has the advantage, over niekas's answer, that if ``fnx`` returns something, you keep that result (and still can manage the warning).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, which was about handling wanrings, not testing them. However, the answer by niekas below does show how to handle warnings.

Comment: Just a note that the above function will not work if your function only intermittently returns a warning because in the event that `fxn()` does not return a warning, then `w` will be an empty list. If `w` is an empty list (i.e. `[]`), then running the code will give you the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. If you're just looking to format or check properties of the captured warnings, then it's better to use a for-loop: `for x in w: print(f'{x.category.__name__}: {str(x.message)}')`

Comment: This approach is useful if one wants to handle warnings without interrupting program execution.

Answer (score 45):

If you just want your script to fail on warnings you can invoke `python` with the [`-W` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w):

```
python -W error foobar.py
```

Comment: To catch a specific warning type, e.g.: `python -W error::RuntimeWarning foobar.py`

Answer (score 25):

Here's a variation that makes it clearer how to work with only your custom warnings.

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")

    # Call some code that triggers a custom warning.
    functionThatRaisesWarning()

    # ignore any non-custom warnings that may be in the list
    w = filter(lambda i: issubclass(i.category, UserWarning), w)

    if len(w):
        # do something with the first warning
        email_admins(w[0].message)
```

Comment: len(<filter object>) fails these days (python 3?).  Adjust a la https://stackoverflow.com/q/3939960/10495893 or similar.

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on [niekas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30368735/11343), but using the `catch_warnings` context manager that resets the warnings behavior to default after context exit:

```
# works in python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fn_triggering_warnings()

# works in python 3.11: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore"):
    fn_triggering_warnings()
```

Answer (score 9):

Catching all warnings can be problematic. You can catch specific warnings. For example, I needed to catch a Pillow warning:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=Image.DecompressionBombWarning)

def process_images():
  try:
    some_process()

  except Image.DecompressionBombWarning as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 6):

In some cases, you need use ctypes to turn warnings into errors. For example:

```
str(b'test')  # no error
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error', BytesWarning)
str(b'test')  # still no error
import ctypes
ctypes.c_int.in_dll(ctypes.pythonapi, 'Py_BytesWarningFlag').value = 2
str(b'test')  # this raises an error
```

Comment: This answer is constructive simply for showing how to error only in certain warning types. For almost any large software project, if you do `warnings.simplefilter('error')` you won't get the traceback for the warning you saw in the logs, but instead get tracebacks from previously-filtered warnings. Using `simplefilter` is also the quickest way to arrive at your answer if you have some CLI invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you can also export an env variable:

```bash
PYTHONWARNINGS=error /usr/bin/run_my_python_utility
```