# How do I catch a numpy warning like it's an exception (not just for testing)?

Tags: python, exception, numpy, warnings, divide-by-zero

I have to make a Lagrange polynomial in Python for a project I'm doing. I'm doing a barycentric style one to avoid using an explicit for-loop as opposed to a Newton's divided difference style one. The problem I have is that I need to catch a division by zero, but Python (or maybe numpy) just makes it a warning instead of a normal exception.

So, what I need to know how to do is to catch this warning as if it were an exception. The related questions to this I found on this site were answered not in the way I needed. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings

class Lagrange:
    def __init__(self, xPts, yPts):
        self.xPts = np.array(xPts)
        self.yPts = np.array(yPts)
        self.degree = len(xPts)-1 
        self.weights = np.array([np.product([x_j - x_i for x_j in xPts if x_j != x_i]) for x_i in xPts])

    def __call__(self, x):
        warnings.filterwarnings("error")
        try:
            bigNumerator = np.product(x - self.xPts)
            numerators = np.array([bigNumerator/(x - x_j) for x_j in self.xPts])
            return sum(numerators/self.weights*self.yPts) 
        except Exception, e: # Catch division by 0. Only possible in 'numerators' array
            return yPts[np.where(xPts == x)[0][0]]

L = Lagrange([-1,0,1],[1,0,1]) # Creates quadratic poly L(x) = x^2

L(1) # This should catch an error, then return 1.
```

When this code is executed, the output I get is:

```
Warning: divide by zero encountered in int_scalars
```

That's the warning I want to catch. It should occur inside the list comprehension.

Comment: Are you quite sure it's `Warning: ...`? Trying things like `np.array([1])/0` I get `RuntimeWarning: ...` as output.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not a duplicate; NumPy has its own internal warning architecture on top of Pythons, which can be specifically controlled (see answer by Bakuríu).

Comment: @gerrit. I stand corrected and learned a new thing. I deleted my original comment to avoid triggering badge collection frenzy.

Comment: Another approach you could use is to simply check if the denominator is 0 before division, which avoids the overhead of fiddling with numpy's warning system. (Although this would probably mean you have to expand the neat list comprehension into a loop checking if any of the denominators is zero.)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

It seems that your configuration is using the `print` option for [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1])/0   #'warn' mode
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
array([0])
>>> np.seterr(all='print')
{'over': 'warn', 'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}
>>> np.array([1])/0   #'print' mode
Warning: divide by zero encountered in divide
array([0])
```

This means that the warning you see is **not** a real warning, but it's just some characters printed to `stdout`(see the documentation for [`seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)). If you want to catch it you can:

1. Use `numpy.seterr(all='raise')` which will directly raise the exception. This however changes the behaviour of all the operations, so it's a pretty big change in behaviour.
2. Use `numpy.seterr(all='warn')`, which will transform the printed warning in a real warning and you'll be able to use the above solution to localize this change in behaviour.

Once you actually have a warning, you can use the `warnings` module to control how the warnings should be treated:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> 
>>> warnings.filterwarnings('error')
>>> 
>>> try:
...     warnings.warn(Warning())
... except Warning:
...     print 'Warning was raised as an exception!'
... 
Warning was raised as an exception!
```

Read carefully the documentation for [`filterwarnings`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) since it allows you to filter only the warning you want and has other options. I'd also consider looking at [`catch_warnings`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) which is a context manager which automatically resets the original `filterwarnings` function:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> with warnings.catch_warnings():
...     warnings.filterwarnings('error')
...     try:
...         warnings.warn(Warning())
...     except Warning: print 'Raised!'
... 
Raised!
>>> try:
...     warnings.warn(Warning())
... except Warning: print 'Not raised!'
... 
__main__:2: Warning:
```

Comment: I think this is a start. But it doesn't actually fix my problem. If I add warnings.warn(Warning())) in my code in the try block, it'll catch the warning. For some reason it doesn't catch the divide by zero warning. Here's the exact warning message:

Warning: divide by zero encountered in int_scalars

Comment: @JohnK. You should edit your question and add the exact output, otherwise we cannot tell what's wrong. It *might* be possible that numpy defines this warning class somewhere and you have to discovere in which subpackage to be able to catch it.
Never mind, I discovered that you should use `RuntimeWarning`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Are you sure? I changed my code to use except RuntimeWarning:. It still isn't working =/

Comment: @JohnK. In the documentation it states that a `RuntimeWarning` is raised. The problem might be that your numpy configuration is using the `print` option, which simply prints the warning but it's not a real warning handled by the `warnings` module... If this is the case you could try to use `numpy.seterr(all='warn')` and try again.

Comment: In my version of `numpy`, you can't use `numpy.seterr(all='error')`, `error` needs to be `raise`.

Comment: @detly Yes, you are right. I don't remember whether old versions allowed `'error'` instead, of if I wrote that because I was distracted.

Comment: `all = 'raise'` raises `FloatingPointException` for all types of warnings, which may not be preferable. Rather, you may want to define an original error handler and use `all = 'call'`. See [*How can I distinguish between two numpy FloatingPointError exceptions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165404/how-can-i-distinguish-between-two-numpy-floatingpointerror-exceptions) for the detail.

Answer (score 69):

To add a little to @Bakuriu's answer:

If you already know where the warning is likely to occur then it's often cleaner to use the [`numpy.errstate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) context manager, rather than  [`numpy.seterr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) which treats all subsequent warnings of the same type the same regardless of where they occur within your code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.r_[1.]
with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
    try:
        a / 0   # this gets caught and handled as an exception
    except FloatingPointError:
        print('oh no!')
a / 0           # this prints a RuntimeWarning as usual
```

---

#### Edit:

In my original example I had `a = np.r_[0]`, but apparently there was a change in numpy's behaviour such that division-by-zero is handled differently in cases where the numerator is all-zeros. For example, in numpy 1.16.4:

```py
all_zeros = np.array([0., 0.])
not_all_zeros = np.array([1., 0.])

with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
    not_all_zeros / 0.  # Raises FloatingPointError

with np.errstate(divide='raise'):
    all_zeros / 0.  # No exception raised

with np.errstate(invalid='raise'):
    all_zeros / 0.  # Raises FloatingPointError
```

The corresponding warning messages are also different: `1. / 0.` is logged as `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide`, whereas `0. / 0.` is logged as `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide`. I'm not sure why exactly this change was made, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that the result of `0. / 0.` is not representable as a number (numpy returns a NaN in this case) whereas `1. / 0.` and `-1. / 0.` return +Inf and -Inf respectively, per the IEE 754 standard.

If you want to catch both types of error you can always pass `np.errstate(divide='raise', invalid='raise')`, or `all='raise'` if you want to raise an exception on *any* kind of floating point error.

Comment: Notably it raises `FloatingPointError`, not `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: This does not work on `Python 3.6.3` with `numpy==1.16.3`. Could you update it please?

Comment: @anilbey Apparently there was a change in numpy's behaviour that means division-by-zero is now handled differently depending on whether the numerator is also (all) zero.

Comment: Why does a RunTimeWarning become a FloatingPointError?

Answer (score 35):

To elaborate on @Bakuriu's answer above, I've found that this enables me to catch a runtime warning in a similar fashion to how I would catch an error warning, printing out the warning nicely:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    try:
        answer = 1 / 0
    except Warning as e:
        print('error found:', e)
```

You will probably be able to play around with placing of the warnings.catch_warnings() placement depending on how big of an umbrella you want to cast with catching errors this way.

Comment: answer = 1 / 0 will raise an error independently... you could give a correct example...

Answer (score 22):

Remove warnings.filterwarnings and add:

```
numpy.seterr(all='raise')
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer, treating the warning like a normal exception

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest this option, a nice Pythonic way of doing it is using context managers. Another previous answer offered this idea but it took me a bit of time to figure out how to use it so I complement the answer.

- Before `Python 3.11`, you had to write the desired action on a different line (and it is the way to do it, I checked in the docs, see below).
- After `Python 3.11`, you can in a very nice way and concise way pass the action to the constructor of the context manager.

See example below.

```
# works in python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fn_triggering_warnings()

# works in python 3.11: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore"):
    fn_triggering_warnings()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error')
    try:
        zstat, pvalue = ztest([0,0], [0], alternative='two-sided')
    except Warning as e:
        print('error found:', e)
```

This could be a better example.