# Why doesn't numpy.power act element-wise on arrays when the exponent is negative?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the difference between numpy.power or ** for negative exponents and / when working with arrays? and why does numpy.power not act element-wise as described in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html).

For example, using python 2.7.3:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> import numpy as np   
>>> A = arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

It appears that ** and numpy.power are not acting element-wise when the exponent is negative

```
>>> A**-1
array([[-9223372036854775808,                    1,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0]])
>>> np.power(A, -1)
array([[-9223372036854775808,                    1,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0]])
```

Whereas / is acting element-wise

```
>>> 1/A
array([[        inf,  1.        ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.14285714,  0.125     ]])
```

I have no such problems when the exponent is positive. Why does it behave differently for negative exponents?

Comment: I have now found that `np.power(A, -1.0)` and `A**-1.0` give the correct result. Does this mean that `np.power` and `**` are using floor division (integer division) for integer negative exponents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is primarily an issue of casting. Operators naturally assume that you do not wish to upcast a number to a different type. The closest value of `2**-1` with integers is 0, this can be verified `int(2**-1) >>>0`.

First create array `A` of type `int`:

```
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> A.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

Copy array `A` to `A_float` as type `float`:

```
>>> A_float = A.astype(float)
>>> A_float.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Run the `**-1` operation on both:

```
>>> A_float**-1
array([[        inf,  1.        ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.14285714,  0.125     ]])

>>> A**-1
array([[-9223372036854775808,                    1,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0],
       [                   0,                    0,                    0]])
```

Observe numpy does not automatically assume you want to complete this operation as float and attempts to accomplish this with integers. If you signify a float in either operand you will obtain a float output due to the "safe" casting rules:

```
>>> A**-1.0
array([[        inf,  1.        ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.14285714,  0.125     ]])
```

Another option is to force `np.power` to cast the operation as a float:

```
>>> np.power(A,-1,dtype=float)
array([[        inf,  1.        ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.14285714,  0.125     ]])
```

I am not sure why you are obtaining a float result with `1/A`. `1.0/A` works just fine however.

Comment: I think `1/A` works because of the line `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct in this, but in general I would be hesitant to write `1/A` and expect a float output.

Comment: Thank you @Ophion, really happy to get my first question answered so quickly!

Answer (score 2):

** or np.power is working, but is performing integer division. Moreover, performing same operations in ipython results in RuntimeWarning of zero division.

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

Now, we can turn same operations into float division by turning operand into float array

```
A = np.array([[0., 1., 2.], [3., 4., 5.], [6., 7., 8.]])
```

Then, 1/, ** and np.power behave identically

Comment: I tried it in ipython and did not get a `RuntimeWarning`.

Comment: @DJCowley It depends on the `numpy` configuration. See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15933741/510937) question and related answer.

Comment: Additionally, there is a global default verbosity in warnings that you can set in disable-warnings.py file. For example, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031783/hide-all-warnings-in-ipython . (This might be digressing from the question, or maybe it's not. After all, we do find useful information regarding np.power and ** using these warnings)