# RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.log10 to calculate the log of an array of probability values. There are some zeros in the array, and I am trying to get around it using

```
result = numpy.where(prob > 0.0000000001, numpy.log10(prob), -10)
```

However, `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10` still appeared and I am sure it is this line caused the warning.

Although my problem is solved, I am confused why this warning appeared again and again?

Comment: `numpy.log10(prob)` is being evaluated before the `where` is being evaluated.

Comment: Note that you can use `numpy.seterr` eventually in combinations with `catch_warnings` to change the behaviour of numpy's division by zero. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15933741/510937) related question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`numpy.log10(prob)` calculates the base 10 logarithm for all elements of `prob`, even the ones that aren't selected by the `where`. If you want, you can fill the zeros of `prob` with `10**-10` or some dummy value before taking the logarithm to get rid of the problem. (Make sure you don't compute `prob > 0.0000000001` with dummy values, though.)

Comment: One way to acomplish this is by using numpy.where twice: `prob_tmp  = numpy.where(prob > 1.0e-10, prob, 1.0e-10)`, `result = numpy.where(prob > 1.0e-10, numpy.log10(prob_tmp), -10)`

Answer (score 44):

You can turn it off with [seterr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)

```
numpy.seterr(divide = 'ignore')
```

and back on with

```
numpy.seterr(divide = 'warn')
```

Comment: Slightly better: use a context manager: `with numpy.errstate(divide='ignore'):`

Answer (score 31):

Just use the `where` argument in `np.log10`

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

prob = np.random.randint(5, size=4) /4
print(prob)

result = np.where(prob > 0.0000000001, prob, -10)
# print(result)
np.log10(result, out=result, where=result > 0)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1.   0.   0.75 0.75]
[  0.         -10.          -0.12493874  -0.12493874]
```

Comment: best clean solution. I would also put it in a little function for reuse.

Comment: ```def safe_log10(x, eps=1e-10):
    result = np.where(x > eps, x, -10)
    np.log10(result, out=result, where=result > 0)
    return result```

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by finding the lowest non-zero number in the array and replacing all zeroes by a number lower than the lowest :p

Resulting in a code that would look like:

```py
def replaceZeroes(data):
  min_nonzero = np.min(data[np.nonzero(data)])
  data[data == 0] = min_nonzero
  return data

 ...

prob = replaceZeroes(prob)
result = numpy.where(prob > 0.0000000001, numpy.log10(prob), -10)
```

Note that all numbers get a tiny fraction added to them.

Answer (score 4):

Just specify `where` to calculate `log10` as follows:

```
 result = np.log10(prob,where=prob>0)
```

Here is a demo:
[image: demo]

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me, use `numpy.sterr` to turn `warnings` off followed by `where`

```
numpy.seterr(divide = 'ignore')
df_train['feature_log'] = np.where(df_train['feature']>0, np.log(df_train['feature']), 0)
```