# How to apply a natural logarithm to a matrix and obtain zero for when the matrix entry is zero

Tags: python, numpy, natural-logarithm

In Python I have a Matrix with some zero values, how can I apply a natural logarithm and obtain zero for when the matrix entry is zero? I am using numpy.log(matrix) to apply the natural logarithm function, but I am getting nan when the matrix entry is equal to zero, and I would like it to be zero instead

Comment: All the options worked great, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
arr = numpy.nan_to_num(numpy.log(matrix))
```

The behavior of nan_to_num replaces all the NaNs by zeroes.

You can find more information here:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Another alternative is to pass a mask to the `where=` argument of the np.log function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where.  The seterr is to turn off the warning.

[RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610198/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log)

In:

```
np.seterr(divide = 'ignore')

matrix = np.array([[10,0,5], [0,10,12]])
np.where(matrix == 0, 0, np.log(matrix))
```

Out:

```
array([[2.30258509, 0.        , 1.60943791],
       [0.        , 2.30258509, 2.48490665]])
```

Comment: Achieving the desired behaviour by turning off warnings is generally not a good practice.

Comment: In this case it's okay and one of the many reason seterr exists.

Comment: You could also use with `np.errstate(divide='ignore'):`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.log1p` it will evaluate to zero if the entry is zero (since the Log of 1 is zero) and the reverse operation is `numpy.expm1`.

You can find more information in the documentation:

1. [Log1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html)
2. [Expm1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html)

Answer (score 0):

`np.log` is a `ufunc` that takes a `where` parameter.  That tells it which elements of `x` will be used in the calculation.  The rest are skipped.  This is best used with a `out` parameter, as follows:

```
In [25]: x = np.array([1.,2,0,3,10,0])                                          
In [26]: res = np.zeros_like(x)                                                 
In [27]: idx = x>0                                                              
In [28]: np.log(x)                                                              
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[28]: 
array([0.        , 0.69314718,       -inf, 1.09861229, 2.30258509,
             -inf])
In [29]: np.log(x, out=res, where=idx)                                          
Out[29]: 
array([0.        , 0.69314718, 0.        , 1.09861229, 2.30258509,
       0.        ])
```