# Cost function of logistic regression outputs NaN for some values of theta

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

While implement logistic regression with only numpy library, I wrote the following code for cost function:

```
#sigmoid function
def sigmoid(z):
  sigma = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
  return sigma
#cost function
def cost(X,y,theta):
  m = y.shape[0]
  z = X@theta
  h = sigmoid(z)
  J = np.sum((y*np.log(h))+((1-y)*np.log(1-h)))
  J = -J/m
  return J
```

Theta is a (3,1) array and X is the training data of shape (m,3). First column of X is ones.
For theta = [0,0,0], cost function outputs 0.693 which is the correct cost, but for theta = [1,-1,1], it outputs:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  """
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  """
nan
```

My code for gradient descent is:

```
#gradientdesc function
#alpha is the learning rate, iter is the number of iterations
def gradientDesc(X,y,theta,alpha,iter):
  m = y.shape[0]
  #d represents the derivative term
  d = np.zeros((3,1))
  for iter in range(iter):

    h = sigmoid(X@theta) - y
    temp = h.T.dot(X)

    d = temp.T
    d/=m
    theta = theta - alpha*d

  return theta
```

But this does not give the correct value of theta. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in `X` large? This might lead to the `sigmoid` returning values close to zero that lead to the warnings you are seeing. Have a look at this thread:
[Divide-by-zero-in-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610198/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log)

Your gradient descent won't work properly unless you solve this issue of values exploding. I would also consider adding regularization in your cost function.

```
J += C * np.sum(theta**2)
```

Comment: The data lies between 20 to 110, which isn't too big, right?

Comment: It's already underfitting, so regularization may not help. Am I correct?

Comment: If it is underfitting then you can skip regularization.
The values you have can lead to large exponents (plug in z = 110 and see for yourself how close you get to zero). `sigmoid` is known to have such saturation issues. Why don't you try normalizing your input to lie between 0 and 1?