# Avoiding a "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log" for array with some zero values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to pass a 2D numpy array `z` into the function:

```py
np.log(np.abs(z))
```

I expect `z` to have a few values that are zero. Is there a way I can override this warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

I know I can just do

```py
np.log(np.abs(z) + 1)
```

or something similar, but what are my options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610198/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log

Comment: You can use `np.ma.log(np.abs(z))`