# Exception handling for 'soft' errors

Tags: python, exception

I'm running [`means2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2) from scipy, and although I'm getting an error message:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py:600: UserWarning:
>   One of the clusters is empty. Re-run kmean with a different
>   initialization.   warnings.warn("One of the clusters is empty. "

when running the following code in a loop:

```
training_2= numpy.random.random_integers(0, 400, size=[50,1]).astype(numpy.float32)
cent, clus= kmeans2(training_2, 3, minit='points')
```

the loop doesn't terminate. I've noticed this behavior with numpy and OpenCV as well.

The usual `try except` block doesn't catch these (for lack of a better term) 'soft' errors; is there another way to handle these errors?

If this isn't possible directly, then is there a way to have a python script read it's own output as it runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an exception, it is a [`warning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html):

> Warning messages are typically issued in situations where it is useful
>   to alert the user of some condition in a program, where that condition
>   (normally) doesn’t warrant raising an exception and terminating the
>   program.

How to handle it, depends on the warning and whether it affects your program execution, you can:

- suppress warnings

  - see [Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)
- treat warnings as errors

  - see [How do I catch a numpy warning like it's an exception (not just for testing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933741/how-do-i-catch-a-warning-in-python-like-its-an-exception-not-just-for-testing)