# How can I distinguish between two numpy FloatingPointError exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, numpy

I'm not really familiar with exceptions in python, so that I'm trying to sort out the problem here. There are two different `FloatingPointError` exceptions in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
np.seterr(divide='raise', invalid='raise')
try:
    np.float64(0.0) / np.float64(0.0)
except FloatingPointError:
    tb = sys.exc_info()

print(tb)

(<type 'exceptions.FloatingPointError'>,
FloatingPointError('invalid value encountered in double_scalars',),
traceback object at 0x10bd50cb0>)


try:
    np.float64(1.0) / np.float64(0.0)
except FloatingPointError:
    tb = sys.exc_info()

print(tb)

(<type 'exceptions.FloatingPointError'>,
FloatingPointError('divide by zero encountered in double_scalars',),
traceback object at 0x10faede60>)
```

I need to define `0/0` operation as 0 in my program, so that I should differ between first and second exceptions. Here is my solution of the problem:

```
if str(tb[1]) == 'invalid value encountered in double_scalars':
    print('first exception found')
else:
    print('second exception found')
```

But I guess I can do it simply with comparing error code or something like that. So how can I do it in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to set a [error callback function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterrcall.html#numpy.seterrcall) via [numpy.seterr()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)

```
class InvalidValueError(Exception): pass
class DivideByZeroError(Exception): pass

def err_handler(err, flag):
    if flag == 8:
        raise InvalidValueError(err)
    if flag == 1:
        raise DivideByZeroError(err)

np.seterrcall(err_handler)
np.seterr(divide='call', invalid='call')
```

In this case, you can `TODO` things according to the error type.

```
try:
    np.float64(0.0) / np.float64(0.0)
    # or `np.float64(1.0) / np.float64(0.0)`
except InvalidValueError:
    # TODO
except DivideByZeroError:
    # TODO
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be  handled with IEEE floating point exceptions, where `0.0/0.0 = NaN` and `1.0/0.0 = inf`.

In your example you could ignore the corresponding numpy warnings,

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```

calculate the result of the division, then tests it with `np.isnan` and `np.isinf` to discriminate between the two cases and handle them appropriately,

```
def validate_division(a, b):
   a = np.float64(a)
   b = np.float64(b)
   res = a/b
   if np.isinf(res):
       print('Dividing by zero')
   elif np.isnan(res):
       print('Both numbers are zero')
   else:
       print('The division is valid')
```

A typical way to ignore the `0.0/0.0` divisions in numpy operations between two arrays `a`, `b` would be,

```
res = a/b
mask = np.isinf(res)
res[mask] = 0 # set the NaN elements to 0.0
```