# Make python crash on warnings

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have a program which uses Pandas. I'm getting:

```
UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.
```

That seems pretty important. However, it tells me where in PANDAS it finds the problem, but I have no idea where in my code it's finding the problem.

If I run python with -Werror, it errors out too early with some warnings that aren't even being displayed.

Comment: You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933741/how-do-i-catch-a-numpy-warning-like-its-an-exception-not-just-for-testing/15934081#15934081) which let you use try/except to catch warning.

Comment: thanks. The answer was what I needed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how does one catch warnings as if they were exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions)