# Getting error while running a classification code in keras

Tags: keras, python-imaging-library, exif

When I run the code from the following link:

https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069#file-classifier_from_little_data_script_2-py

I get the following error:

> Using TensorFlow backend. Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
>   /home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:692:
>   UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data. Expecting to read 80000 bytes
>   but only got 0. Skipping tag 64640 "Skipping tag %s" % (size,
>   len(data), tag))

I am Using Ubuntu.

Tried Solution : change 'w' to 'wb' in line 70 and 81.

Thnx in advance

Comment: Hi Hitesh, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and learn how to ask and format your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thnx, I will Take care of this

Comment: some one please reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because some of the images have corrupted exif info. You can just remove the exif info of all your images to remove this warning.

The python package [`piexif`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piexif) can help you. you can use the following code to remove the exif info of an image:

```
import piexif
# suppose im_path is a valid image path
piexif.remove(im_path)
```

You can find more discussion [here](http://forums.fast.ai/t/help-needed-pil-corrupt-exif-data/3497/3).

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to imply that you try to use TIFF images (rather than JPEGs) and that the PIL library can´t import these without an error (`Possibly corrupt EXIF data`).

I suggest you try some test JPEGs to make sure your images can be imported correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to catch these warnings, so that I can print out the filename of these corrupted images? All of my images have jpg/jpeg extensions, so they are mixed within.