# How do I make pytest crash on a warning?

Tags: python, pytest, warnings

this is an expansion of [How do I find where a "Sorting because non-concatenation" warning is coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486927/how-do-i-find-where-a-sorting-because-non-concatenation-warning-is-coming-from?noredirect=1#comment95781254_54486927).

I'm still getting the same warning, in my pytest. I've looked at several questions here, and done:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
```

which is suggested in [How do I catch a numpy warning like it's an exception (not just for testing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933741/how-do-i-catch-a-numpy-warning-like-its-an-exception-not-just-for-testing/15934081#15934081)

However, when I run pytest, it still gives me the error, but nothing actually errors...

Answer (score 16):

Try passing the [`-W`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html) flag when you run pytest, like this:

```
pytest -W error::RuntimeWarning
```

Specify the kind of warning you want to turn in to an error e.g. DeprecationWarning, FutureWarning, UserWarning.

Comment: How can I set this in a config file so I don't need to manually pass it on every pytest call? I don't see a longhand name for the `-W` option?

Comment: The same option can be set in the pytest.ini or pyproject.toml file using the `filterwarnings` ini option. [Link to docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html#controlling-warnings) with examples of the syntax for pytest.ini and pyproject.toml.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make every warning raise an error then just use

```bash
pytest -W error
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share another solution in hopes that it will help others as I spent way too long trying to solve this.

I specifically only wanted a single test to fail on a warning, not all of them. In my case an exception was being raised within a thread I wanted to test for and discovered the `pytest.mark.filterwarnings` decorator can be used for this purpose.

The traceback:

```
        raise SerialException(
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

        warnings.warn(pytest.PytestUnhandledThreadExceptionWarning(msg))

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
```

The decorator to catch it:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("error::pytest.PytestUnhandledThreadExceptionWarning")
```