# In NumPy: How to detect whether an argument is a "ragged nested sequences"

Tags: python, numpy, deprecated

If `obj` is a list of "ragged nested sequences", like `obj = [1, 2, [3, 4]]`, then
`np.array(obj)` produces a warning: "Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences ... is deprecated..."

How can I check in advance (without getting the warning) whether a given value is defined as "ragged nested sequences"?

Comment: `np.array(obj, dtype=object)` will silence the warning.  You can then check the `shape`.  `np.array(obj, dtype=int)` will raise an error if it is ragged.  Basically it's "ragged" if `np.array` can't make a 'clean' numeric dtype array.

Comment: thanks. though at the end what i am looking for is a function that returns True/False indicating if obj is ragged or not, without issuing a warning.

Comment: There are cases where it will raise an error, regardless.  If the first dimension(s) match, but trailing ones differ.  The key thing is that `np.array` tries first to make a multidimensional numeric array.  The ragged array (and warning) is a falback option. `raggedness` is something you should seek to avoid when constructing the nested list.

Comment: Specific [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933741/how-do-i-catch-a-numpy-warning-like-its-an-exception-not-just-for-testing) can be promoted to errors and handled with `try`, `except` blocks. This would use `np.array` inside `try` to raise the warning, but will stop working after the deprecation is removed.

Comment: yes that will work  - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it.  The function `get_shape(a)` is a recursive function that returns either the shape of `a` as a tuple, or `None` if `a` does not have a regular shape (i.e. `a` is ragged).  The tricky part is actually the function `is_scalar(a)`: we want `string` and `bytes` instances, and arbitrary noniterable objects (such as `None`, or `Foo()` where `Foo` is `class Foo: pass`) to be considered scalars.  `np.iscalar()` does some of the work; an attempt to evaluate `len(a)` does the rest.  The NumPy docs suggest the simple expression `np.ndim(a) == 0`, but that will invoke the array creation for `a`, which will trigger the warning if `a` is ragged. (The `is_scalar` function might miss some cases, so test it carefully with typical data that you use.)

```
import numpy as np


def is_scalar(a):
    if np.isscalar(a):
        return True
    try:
        len(a)
    except TypeError:
        return True
    return False


def get_shape(a):
    """
    Returns the shape of `a`, if `a` has a regular array-like shape.

    Otherwise returns None.
    """
    if is_scalar(a):
        return ()
    shapes = [get_shape(item) for item in a]
    if len(shapes) == 0:
        return (0,)
    if any([shape is None for shape in shapes]):
        return None
    if not all([shapes[0] == shape for shape in shapes[1:]]):
        return None
    return (len(shapes),) + shapes[0]


def is_ragged(a):
    return get_shape(a) is None
```

For example,

```
In [114]: is_ragged(123)
Out[114]: False

In [115]: is_ragged([1, 2, 3])
Out[115]: False

In [116]: is_ragged([1, 2, [3, 4]])
Out[116]: True

In [117]: is_ragged([[[1]], [[2]], [[3]]])
Out[117]: False

In [118]: is_ragged([[[1]], [[2]], [[3, 99]]])
Out[118]: True
```