# Size of an array of unknown type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size

I have an array `arr` which is not a `numpy` type. I would like to find the size of this array. A simple search shows options like `len(arr)` and `arr.shape` if it is a `numpy` array. `len` seems to be working only for 1D array. If I do `arr=numpy.array(arr)`, then I can do `arr.shape`. Is there a direct way to get the shape of `arr`?

The array `arr` is returned from a function and I do not know the operations inside. A simple of `print` of `arr` gives `[array([2, 3, 1, ... ]), array([5, 2, 9, ... ]) ]`. `type(arr)` results in `<class 'list'>`

This being the case, how to find the size of `arr` "directly"? Something like `(2, N)`

Comment: What kind of array is it if it's not a numpy array? How did you create it?

Comment: "I have an array arr which is not a numpy type" what does that mean? what is `type(arr)` returning? Your question doesn't really make sense. Please provide more information (again, like, what does `type(arr)` return?)

Comment: It is returned from a function and I do not know the operations inside. A simple of `print` shows `[array([2, 3, 1, ... ]), array([5, 2, 9, ... ]) ]`

Comment: `type(arr)` results in `<class 'list'>`

Comment: You have a list of numpy arrays.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a direct way to find the size?

Comment: You can loop over the list, getting the size of each array with the `.shape` property.

Comment: If the arrays have the same size, you can probably have `np.array(arr).shape`

Comment: @GiovanniTardini Thats a known solution. I am looking for other options than converting to a `numpy` array.

Comment: It isn't an array at all, it is a `list`, and `len(mylist)` is the direct way to get the size of a list. What is it **exactly** that you are expecting? You haven't actually told us what you mean by "size". Normally, in Python, that would mean `len(myobj)`

Comment: You use of `size` is a little ambiguous. Are you trying to get the length/shape or actual memory size? If the former, there's no general solution for arbitrary objects. If the latter, then [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In my case, it being a `list` of `length` 2 with each containing `N` elements, I am looking for `(2,N)` as an answer directly.

Comment: @SKPS, are you sure that all the items in the list will have the same shape?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes

Comment: One option might be the function `get_shape(a)` in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794349/in-numpy-how-to-detect-whether-an-argument-is-a-ragged-nested-sequences/72794813#72794813

Comment: If you happen to know that all the elements in the list are NumPy arrays, a simple solution is `(len(arr),) + arr[0].shape` (which is just a slight variation of @Barmar's answer). You'll have to tweak that if it is possible for `arr` to be an empty list.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I thought I would get to know some interesting Python function today for this size need. But apparently it is not the case. Maybe it is due to mixed type of my data. I wonder if this is possible to be listed as a Python function in future.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of numpy arrays, so you can get the sizes with:

```
sizes = [a.size for a in arr]
```

If you assume that all the arrays are the same shape, you can get the size of the first element and combine that with the length of the list.

```
size = (len(arr), *arr[0].shape)
```

Comment: Is there a "blackbox" like solution? i.e. without knowing the underlying type/structure?

Comment: Not really. This is not a general structure.

Comment: @SKPS how could there possibly be a "black box" solution? The "size" of an object is not even something that is well defined.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is the whole point of this question. Looking for something that I do not know. Looks like there is no "something" solution for this particular need.

Comment: Right, there's nothing like this, because every case is different. There's no way for a general function to know which objects it should drill into and which should be counted as a single element.

Comment: `shape` is an attribute of `numpy` arrays - and other structures model it.  You have a list of arrays.  `len` works for the 'outer' layer.  Also works an array.

Comment: @hpaulj He's trying to get one result that shows the combined shape of all the nested collections, no matter what the actual datatypes are. The `shape` attribute of numpy doesn't get the shapes of nested objects, either.