# numpy's `seterr(all='warn')` does not raise a Warning

Tags: numpy, warnings

My understanding is that python's default warnings are not python `Warning`s, but printed messages.  So I went ahead and used [np.seterr()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) to try to catch them:

```
import numpy as np

np.seterr(all='warn')

try:
    np.array([1]) / np.array([0])
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception('exception caught in except block') from e
```

I'd expect the code above to catch the warning in the except block, though only the printed warning message is displayed (python 3.10.6, numpy 1.21.5).

From the documentation on [np.seterr()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

> warn: Print a RuntimeWarning (via the Python warnings module).

Which, read carefully, does say that it only prints a warning using the Warning module rather than raising a Warning ... but I'm a bit confused as to why its built this way.  What use is setting something to 'warn' if not the case above?

The behavior also seems inconsistent with [this popular, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933741/how-do-i-catch-a-numpy-warning-like-its-an-exception-not-just-for-testing/15934081#15934081)

Comment: _"I'd expect the code above to catch the warning in the except block"_  Warnings aren't exceptions and are [caught differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5644836/11082165). _"The behavior also seems inconsistent"_ In that answer, the author promoted warnings to exceptions with `warnings.filterwarnings("error")`

Comment: that does answer my question, thank you!  I had checked if `Warning` was a subclass of `Exception` (it is) and assumed they were handled similarly.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Cheers