# Numpy and numdifftools multidimensional function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using the package numddifftools to calculate the hessians of a multidimensional function (from R^n to R^n). While changing the code to use numpy arrays instead of lists,  I discovered that doing so broke the code. Specifically:

```
import numpy as np 
import numdifftools as nd

def function(x):

    out = np.zeros(2)
    out[0] = x[0] - x[1]**2/2.0

    return float(out[0])

tempHessian = nd.Hessian(function, method='complex')
tempHessian([0.4,0.4])
```

Produces the error:
...\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part

and gives a zero hessian.

However, this one works fine:

```
import numpy as np 
import numdifftools as nd

def function(x):

    return x[0] - x[1]**2/2.0

tempHessian = nd.Hessian(function, method='complex')
tempHessian([0.4,0.4])
```

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should try to figure out what line in your code is triggering the warning. You can turn warnings into exceptions via the warnings module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions

Comment: The problem is "float(out[0])"  you are converting the matrix in a "real" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `out` is created like this:

```
    out = np.zeros(2)
```

it has type `numpy.float64`. You can't assign a complex value to such an array.  Depending on which version of numpy that you are using, you'll get a warning or an error.

The [*complex step method*](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/) for numerical differentiation requires that your function works with complex values.  Forcing `out` to be `numpy.float64` breaks that method.  Converting the return value to floating point with `float(out[0])` also breaks the method.

You can try something like this:

```
def function(x):

    out = np.zeros(2, dtype=x.dtype)
    out[0] = x[0] - x[1]**2/2.0

    return out[0]
```

This creates `out` with the same data type as `x`.  So if `x` is complex, the return value is also complex, as required by the complex step method.

(Of course, we don't know why you create `out` to have size 2, when only the first element is used. Presumably this is a simplification of the actual code that you are working with.)

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Yes, I simplified the problem to understand it better and post it here. :)