# Numpy zero-division in try-except block, which raises "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" and strange results

Tags: python, numpy

Code

```
s = np.zeros(2)
try:
    a = s[0]/s[1]
except:
    a = 10.0
print(a)
```

raises warning as mentioned in the title of the question and prints nan. It's rather strange, isn't it? How can it be explained and corrected?

Comment: NumPy is behaving correctly. If you wanted something else, you need to specify (both to us and to Python) what you want to happen.

Comment: It seems, that except section doesn't work and I don't understand why...

Comment: It's not an exception.

Comment: I want variable a should have the value of 10.0, not nan

Comment: Dear user2357112, why zero dividing doesn't raise an exception?

Comment: You're using NumPy math, not regular Python scalars. NumPy doesn't raise an exception for this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you expect a divide-by-zero *exception*.  The run-time system doesn't work this way: you get a *warning* and a result of `nan`.  Thus, your exception block doesn't get tripped.  Instead, try this:

```
if s[1]:
    a = s[0] / s[1]
else:
    a = 10.0
```

Comment: If you want to trap warnings as well as exceptions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions#30368735).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is quite clear. But what I don't understand is why the code does not raise an exception?

Comment: Other words for what purpose it was done that way - just warning, not exception?

Comment: To answer "what purpose", you'll need to read through the language design postings; I expect that there is at least one explanation in the PEP documents.

Comment: The application I have locally is that we want to work with large AI data sets with some missing values.  It's very convenient to have `nan` semantics that inherently support that concept, rather than having to write custom software to properly fill in `nan` and skip or impute said values.

Comment: But from my point of view it's not the question of python as language - it's concerning only numpy, isn't it?

Comment: Ah -- right.  It's just numpy.  PEP references are useless.