# FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like not to use the non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing so that the script will support future release of Python when this changes.

Below is the code that i am using for plotting the graph:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(Example.csv,delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True, 
    converters={0: str2date})

p1, = host.plot(data["column_1"], data["column_2"], "b-", label="column_2")
p2, = par1.plot(data["column_1"], data['column_3'], "r-", label="column_3")
p3, = par2.plot(data["column_1"], data["column_4"], "g-", label="column_4")

host.set_xlim([data["column_1"][0], data["column_1"][-1]])
host.set_ylim(data["column_2"].min(), data["column_2"].max())
par1.set_ylim(data["column_3"].min(), data["column_3"].max())
par2.set_ylim(data["column_4"].min(), data["column_4"].max())
```

Comment: I suspect the offending code is in matplotlib. Is your version up to date?

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes, i have updaed version.

Comment: You can probably turn the warning into an error [using the first two lines of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30368735/5067311) (I haven't used it ever myself). That might tell you which module and code line the error is coming from.

Comment: Actually, here "data" is a numpy array. and "data["column_1"]" is a non tuple sequence. I am not facing this warning with numpy==1.14.5. The problem is in updated versions of numpy. Is there a way i can convert this to "arr[tuple(seq)]" ?

Comment: No, the problem is not the updated version of numpy. The warning is new in numpy and signals a future deprecation, so you need to fix _everything else_.

Comment: What's this `str2date` converter?

Answer (score 17):

I can reproduce the warning with:

```
In [313]: x = np.zeros((4,2))
In [315]: x[:,1]
Out[315]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

By replacing the `:` with a `slice(None)` we can write this indexing as:

```
In [316]: x[[slice(None),1]]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[316]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

It really should be a tuple, rather than a list:

```
In [317]: x[(slice(None),1)]
Out[317]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
In [318]: x[tuple([slice(None),1])]
Out[318]: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

The warning tells us that the list format used to be ok, but will in the future produce an error.

I don't see anything your code that does this sort of slice in a list indexing.

`data` from `genfromtxt` is a structured array, so indexing by field name is normal: `data["column_1"]`.  So it's likely that the warning is generated within the `plot` code.  But we don't have any clue as to where.  The warning doesn't give any sort of error stack trace, do it?

So without a sample array like `data`, or a csv file like `Example.csv`, we can't reproduce the warning, and dig further.

---

For a start I'd put some sort of `print` between each of your code lines.  The goal is to pin down which `matplotlib` call is producing the warning.

If for example it is produced in

```
host.set_xlim([data["column_1"][0], data["column_1"][-1]])
```

I might try changing that call to

```
host.set_xlim((data["column_1"][0], data["column_1"][-1]))
```

or

```
host.set_xlim(data["column_1"][0], data["column_1"][-1])
```

That's a bit of wild guess...

### edit

[FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594235/futurewarning-using-a-non-tuple-sequence-for-multidimensional-indexing-is-depre)

This latest SO, helps us identify a problem function in the `scipy.stats` package.  It constructs a list of slices, and uses it without further conversion to tuple.

Comment: The sad thing is really that users expect the libraries to work out of the box, but when it comes to identifying potential problems (e.g. by providing reproducible examples) any request for those is ignored.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest reproducible examples are often hard to construct, especially when a lot of users are working with proprietary data, under time pressure. Sometimes it's easier (or appears easier) to shrug and either ignore it or figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 9):

Upadating Scipy fixed this problem in my case. Cause the Scipy.stats class was deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

I would have tested this before posting (well, I did test it for areas where I was having the same problem), but I suspect that this will help you. Using your first line where you call a plot above, use tuple type casting as I've shown and do the same to your other lines calling plot.

```
p1, = host.plot(tuple(data["column_1"]), 
                tuple(data["column_2"]), 
                "b-", label="column_2")
```

When I studied numpy methods of indexing, the warning made a little more sense. However, I don't really understand why things need to go this way.