# Avoid deprecation warning Python FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Hi all I am trying to avoid this future warning in python, stranged because it is refering to scipy and i haven't imported scipy library.

```
%matplotlib inline
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc, Rectangle, ConnectionPatch
from matplotlib.offsetbox import  OffsetImage
import squarify
from functools import reduce






fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)

ax.set_xlim([0,120])
ax.set_ylim([0,80])

x_coord = [i[0] for i in ozil_action["location"]]
y_coord = [i[1] for i in ozil_action["location"]]

#shades: give us the heat map we desire
# n_levels: draw more lines, the larger n, the more bluerry it loos
sns.kdeplot(x_coord, y_coord, shade = "True", color = "green", n_levels = 30)
plt.show()
```

Future Warning

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:1713: 
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; 
use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. 
In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, 
which will result either in an error or a different result.

  return np.add.reduce(sorted[indexer] * weights, axis=axis) / sumval
```

Versions of the packages used for my anaconda environment
numpy, seaborn,matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
np.__version__
'1.16.4'


scipy.__version__
'1.1.0'


matplotlib.__version__
'3.0.2'

seaborn.__version__
'0.9.0'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/4225229 - does this help?

Comment: Not really i am trying to fix my code, not hiding potential future issues

Comment: Is that the full traceback?  I assume another package, such as `sns` is using `scipy.stats`.  And it, plus `scipy` needs a more up to date version.

Comment: What's the `numpy` version?  `scipy` version?

Comment: import numpy as np
np.__version__
'1.16.4'


scipy.__version__
'1.1.0'


matplotlib.__version__
'3.0.2'



seaborn.__version__
'0.9.0'

Comment: You need a newer `scipy` to silence this warning.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56579536, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595447