# Shape command does not return the column number when the data frame has only column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

The dataset is mentioned as below
The defines variable is exam .
exam.shape = (29,2)

```
    |Hours| |Pass| 
0   |0.5 |    |0|  
1   |0.75|    |0|  
2   |1.00|    |0|  
3   |1.25|    |0|  
4   |1.50|    |0|
```

Clear image is attached in the screenshot

[image: Data set image - Exam]

```
X = exam.Hours  
y = exam.Pass 

X.shape = (29,)  # The column number one is not mentioned   
y.shape = (29,) # The column value is not mentioned
```

Expected Outcome

```
X.shape = (29,1)    
y.shape = (29,1)
```

Comment: A column a Series, wjich is a 1d object, hnce the single shape value.  Shape is a tuple, hence the (29,) display.

Answer (score 1):

Both arrays are one-dimensional and you are looking to add one extra dimension. You need to unsqueeze a new axis on your arrays.

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(29)

>>> x.shape
(29,)
```

Either using indexing:

```
>>> x = x[..., np.newaxis] # i.e. x[..., None]

>>> x.shape
(29, 1)
```

Or with the [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) utility:

```
>>> x = np.expand_dims(x, -1)

>>> x.shape
(29, 1)
```

Comment: Columns of a pandas dataframe are pandas Series, not numpy arrays.  cf https://stackoverflow.com/q/68768549/901925

Answer (score 0):

```
In [200]: df
Out[200]: 
   age  rank  height  weight
0   20     2     155      53
1   15     7     159      60
2   34     6     180      75
3   40     5     163      80
4   60     1     170      49
In [201]: df.shape
Out[201]: (5, 4)
```

The following is a Series,which only has length, not columns:

```
In [202]: df['height']
Out[202]: 
0    155
1    159
2    180
3    163
4    170
Name: height, dtype: int64
In [203]: df['height'].shape
Out[203]: (5,)
```

Index with a list returns a dataframe with column number.  Note the difference in display:

```
In [204]: df[['height']]
Out[204]: 
   height
0     155
1     159
2     180
3     163
4     170
In [205]: df[['height']].shape
Out[205]: (5, 1)
```