# How do I check for async functions in Python that have been called without await?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio

Let's say we have the following functions:

```
async def x1():
    print("inside x1")

async def x2():
    print("inside x2")

async def main():
    await x1()
    x2()
    await asyncio.sleep(5) 

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I will get a warning of the following:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'x2' was never awaited
```

Are there any way to make Python raises an error instead of just printing a warning?

Comment: i don't see where this error could possibly be raised.  The warning refers to a thing that didn't happen - "x was never awaited" - so there is no specific line of code where an exception occurred.

Comment: I understand that. Forgetting adding await in a front of awaitable function that meant to be called will result in a code bug. My question is how to detect code bugs that are related to forgetting the keyword `await`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions